# When pressing the arrow keys on the keyboard, there are different spacing. Swiper JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, swiper.js

I using swiper JS.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="swiper-container">

        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide">Halo 10</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide3</div>
        </div>
```

my js

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  direction: 'vertical',
  mousewheel: true,
  allowTouchMove: true,
  slidesPerView:1,
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    type: 'fraction',
    
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev'
  }
});

$("body").keyup(function(e) {

  if(e.keyCode == 38) { // top
    console.log('top')
    $('.swiper-button-prev').click();
  }
  else if(e.keyCode == 40) { // bottom
    $('.swiper-button-next').click();

  }
});
```

demo is here [link](https://dediwibisono17.github.io/swiper/)

it will look different if we click the arrow on the side and press the down/up arrow on the keyboard.

My hope is that when pressing the arrows on the keyboard, the behavior can be the same as clicking the arrows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use keydown event and prevent its default behaviour to scroll down and scrollup browser bar.Here is the right code:

```
$(function () {
      var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        direction: 'vertical',
        mousewheel: true,
        allowTouchMove: true,
    
        slidesPerView:1,
     
        pagination: {
          el: '.swiper-pagination',
          type: 'fraction',
          
        },
        navigation: {
          nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
          prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev'
        }
      });
    
      $("body").keydown(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
        if(e.keyCode == 38) { // top
          console.log('top');
          $('.swiper-button-prev').click();
        }
        else if(e.keyCode == 40) { // bottom
          console.log('bottom');
          $('.swiper-button-next').click();
    
        }
      
      });
    
     
    });
```

Comment: All pleasure mine.